# Does "virgin plains" make sense in an English poetic composition?

Tags: word-choice, metaphors

I want to point readers to **the (virgin) plains which have been far from man-made structures, without any changes over the years**. In its original Persian version, for *virgin* I used an adjective which is only used for humans and horses! But I do not know whether or not it makes sense in English to do the same. Surely *virgin* has many equivalent meanings in Persian like *noble*, *original* and *gentle* not only the meaning on ground of having sex or not.

There are some similar compositions like: *virgin prairies*, *noble plains* & *noble prairies*.

Please write me which of above is best for the purpose mentioned; and if you have a better term I would be grateful to know it.

Comment: Persian has an adjective for a horse that hasn't had sex yet?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm :)) You killed me by this = You made my day! No dear! The equivalent Persian doesn't mean only that but have two meanings. One is that you said and one means "noble","gentle" and "original" and is used for both sexes and horses. It is better to edit it. It may make confusion in audiences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another word you might consider is ***pristine***. From NOAD:

> **pristine** (*adj*.) in its original condition; unspoiled

To get back to your question, though, the word *virgin* can be used in a metaphorical sense:

> The skaters ventured onto the virgin ice.

When used to describe *prairies* or *plains*, though, I might be inclined to think that *virgin prairies* were not just never built upon, but perhaps unploughed and never furrowed as well.

Comment: And in the case *virgin territory* it means that nobody has **ever** gone there before i.e., it remains unexplored.  That's how I would interpret *virgin plains* and *virgin prairies*.

Comment: @Jim: Your comment begs the response "...to boldly go where no man has gone before." - William Shatner